# Objective C create new class which is an image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class, uiimage

Sorry I'm new to Objective C and OOP, and I'm trying to understand how to use classes. I have searched everywhere but can't find a clear answer.

So in my game I want a NEW ball to be created when i tap and drag an image of a ball. Would I create a ball class, and when I tap the ball, an instance of the ball class will be created. How do I set that class to be an image of a ball?

Comment: Sorry I'll make it clearer, this is what i want to make.

1) There's a cannon (UIImage) and a button (UIImage) with a tap gesture recogniser.

2) When then button is pressed, a ball appears at the end of the cannon and is "shot out".

3) You can press the button as many times as you like with an unlimited number of balls coming out.

4) Would you create a ball class, instance it. How would you give the class a UIImage of a ball? Also when you create an instance of a class in the view controller, you give it a name "newClass", if many instances are created won't they all have the same name?

Comment: If there is an unlimited number of balls that can be created, how can I give each a different name?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide much detail, but i guess you will create more than one ball in some View controlled by a whateverViewController. One simple approach would be a collection class holding the balls created.

IN your whateverViewController class :

....
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableSet *balls;  // release in dealloc

On tap - a ball gets created and added to the set.

Your ball class then implements whatever you need for a ball and holds a UIImage for display.
....
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImage* ballImage;  // release in dealloc